# Deploying to the Android Marketplace

Tags: android, deployment, google-play

If I want to deploy to the Android Market it looks like I have two options:

1. Create my own keystore and upload. When I update my app use that keystore on my APK to ensure that users are given the option to update.
2. Do step 1, but also implement Application Licensing which will put controls on how the app is used.

Am I correct to assume that step 1 means that anyone could copy my APK once it is purchased from the Android Market and install it anywhere they wish?

How common is it for people to use Application Licensing and is it the defacto approach?

My app will be paid and I want to ensure I am taking the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I correct to assume that step 1 means that anyone could copy my APK once it is purchased from the Android Market and install it anywhere they wish?

Yes you are correct, it would be extremely easy to copy your application.

> How common is it for people to use Application Licensing and is it the defacto approach?

I would say it's very common since it's the only way to verify the licence against the Android Market, though I don't have any stats on this. Otherwise you would need to implement your own "Market" and verify purchases in your own.

> My app will be paid and I want to ensure I am taking the best approach.

Use LVL, DO NOT use the default implementation. Watch the LVL session from the 2011 IO for a how to.

Answer (score 1):

Often times, people will not simply download an app and copy it anywhere they would like. However, it is possible through some apps and other software for users to copy off APKs from their phones (even though they aren't suppose to). In my opinion, if you app is paid, you should implement Applicant Licensing. It is a very useful tool to help in preventing people from stealing your APKs (in other words, downloading it and then trying to install it some where else) as it checks on start up to ensure that the app is on the phone that purchased it. Otherwise, for free apps, I don't really see the neccessity because it's free and anyone could have downloaded it.